# SQLITE3 return count based on column's value

Tags: sqlite, count

Example of my table :

```
ID    MACHINE    RESULT
1     A            fail
2     A            pass
3     B            pass
4     A            fail
```

The next query gets the number of pass and fail from all the MACHINE

```
SELECT RESULT, COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY RESULT
```

The answer is :

2 fail 
2 pass

My goal is to get the pass and fail count from a specific MACHINE .
I tried the follow :

```
SELECT RESULT, COUNT(*) FROM my_table  WHERE MACHINE = 'A' GROUP BY RESULT
```

It doesnt work as expected . 
And I'm expecting :

2 fail
1 pass

Where is my mistake ? :<

Comment: Can't really spot an error, what is your output?

Comment: 0 Rows returned from: SELECT RESULT, COUNT(*) FROM my_table  WHERE MACHINE = 'A' GROUP BY RESULT(took 8ms).doesnt help at all ....

Comment: What is returned when you query `SELECT RESULT FROM my_table WHERE MACHINE = 'A'`?

Comment: nothing is returned ( 0 rows )

Comment: What do `SELECT MACHINE from my_table` and `SELECT RESULT FROM my_table WHERE MACHINE LIKE 'A'` return?

Comment: the 1st query : returns all the column named MACHINE ,
the 2nd returns : nothing

Comment: Ok so the column is found and spelled correctly. Must be the comparison then. Mess around with it, try `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MACHINE == 'A'`, `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MACHINE = 'A'`, `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MACHINE IS 'A'`, `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MACHINE = "A"` etc. until you get a match.

Comment: Wait, try this: `SELECT RESULT, COUNT(*) FROM my_table  WHERE MACHINE="A" GROUP BY RESULT`, I think that will work.

Comment: the newest query that you gave here is the same as the  2nd query on my main post  :} . It doesnt work :{

Comment: Syntactically everything should be OK. If you can't even select rows in which the machine is A, using a simple `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MACHINE="A"`, then something else is wrong. You sure it's sqlite? Hidden characters in the machine name perhaps? -- BTW the that last query is not the same, notice the lack of spaces before and after the `=`.

Comment: Yes it is sqlite .. using sqlite database editor to test the query before using it in my code . let me retype the query from 0

Comment: Select machine, length(machine). Function will return number of symbols in machine column. Look at it and you will probably see some mismatch, that indicates that your machine column has some sinvisible symbols like line fedd, tab, carriage return

Comment: You should rebuild the database and try again, nothing wrong with the query. It's the database that is contaminated I believe.

Comment: Giorgi , I tried the select function to find data about the machine column . And as you expected i get : no such column ... i will examine this issue ...

Comment: Hi Fish and Giorgi , i examined this issue . i found that all the cells in the RESULT column included the \n character . after ive deleted this symbol the query is working fine .

Comment: And you can **optimize** your query a bit if you **limit the counting to a single field**, by changing this `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(MACHINE)`